# Script to generate signed apk for multiple projects android studio

Tags: android

I understand how to generate a signed apk from android studio-> Build menu, but if I have several projects is it possible to automate this task so that for all the projects I could run some script which automatically builds signed apks without me having to generate them one by one ?

Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

Yes this can be done by creating a signed build configuration and specifying the keystore information. This is done by adding a couple sections to `build.gradle`:

First create the signed build type that uses release mode and runs proguard:

```
android {
  buildTypes {
    signed {
        debuggable false
        minifyEnabled true
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.signed
    }
  }
}
```

Then add the signing configuration (supply your own values):

```
android {
  signingConfigs {
      signed {
          storeFile file('keystore.jks')
          storePassword 'storepassword'
          keyAlias 'key'
          keyPassword 'keypassword'
      }
  }
}
```

Then, you can build from the command line by typing `./gradlew assembleSigned` (for Mac OSX) or `gradlew assembleSigned` (for Windows).

You can also use the `installSigned` build task to build and install on a connected device.

Comment: :myapp:transformclassesAndResourcesWithProguardForSigned  FAILED any ideas

Comment: My answer is the answer to your question ,if you have another problem you should post another question. I'm guessing you don't have the keystore in the place gradle expects it to be but I really have no idea without more information!

Comment: Yes I understand, I am wondering if I may have done something incorrect that would have lead to this error, my build release/debug builds fine in and studio